# Can I access the Parallel Port normally when using USB to Parallel Port adapter?

Tags: windows, delphi, usb, delphi-2009, parallel-port

**Preliminary story**

There is this program which uses the Parallel Port to synchronize with other hardware. It will set the Parallel Port output to a specified (byte) value. This works without problems when using the built-in Parallel Port of a PC. The target platforms are Windows XP to 7, all worked fine so far. Source code is in Delphi, accessible and can be modified.

**How it works**

In Delphi I can use the *[io.dll](http://www.geekhideout.com/iodll.shtml)* to set the value of the Parallel Port, but there are also other solutions available, like *inpout32.dll* or *port.dll*. I call something like `PortOut`, specify a port number and the byte value and the port is set.

**What I now want to do - and where I need help**

Now the change: this needs to work on a machine which has no Parallel Port built-in (not even on the mainboard). There are several options available:

- use a USB to Parallel Port adapter to add a LPT port to the PC
- use a PCI card which adds a LPT port to the PC
- use a PCI Express card which adds a LPT port to the PC

I am currently heading for and concentrating on the easiest and cheapest possibility: a USB to Parallel Port adapter.

**Main question**

There seem to be differences between Parallel Port adapters which are made to connect just a printer and other adapters which seem to be more powerful. Is there really a difference? Or can I just use one of these 5$ printer-adapters, plug in my own hardware and access the port from Delphi code? Or do I need a special adapter? Has anyone experience with this? There is a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182646/controlling-a-parallel-port-via-usb-adaptor-on-modern-hardware-and-os), but the different adapter types (if existent) are not mentioned there. [This page](http://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~heha/bastelecke/Rund%20um%20den%20PC/USB2LPT/index.html.en) suggests that there are indeed differences:

> Contrary to all other USB parallel ports which can connect to printers only, this makes  connection to most hardware.

I hope there exists a solution via USB because for this you don't have to open the PC, which means the adapter can be added on demand.

**Sub-question**

Do you have experience with PCI (Express) solution? I have to use one if the USB approach is not successful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since I've been wrestling with this very thing recently here's what I've discovered; If you mean by using IO port addressing (indicated by your reference to inpout32.dll), no. Unless your USB-parallel port driver supports full port emulation or virtualization, which most do not, this is generally not possible. If you need to directly access the port to do normal "bit-twiddling", you should get a separate Parallel port PCI-card. Most of them present themselves as normal IO at the standard address(es). I am presuming you're not planning on using the parallel port to actually communicate with a printer, right?

What is interesting is that USB-Serial adapters are much easier to use since they appear as simple virtual devices where you can merely "open" them using a simple stream; TFileStream.Create("COM1", fmOpenRead) or Windows.CreateFile("COM2", ...);

Here is some devices that purport to do full emulation of a parallel port through USB:

https://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~ygu/bastelecke/PC/USB2LPT/index.en.htm

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your insights! We now also did some tests here and our findings correspond with yours. There are some hacky ways to get a grip on the USB device (also via CreateFile), but setting single bits via WriteFile fails, (probably) because the adapter then sends a response and waits for answer. And no, we have no printer attached. We just want to set single bits for custom devices. But no way :( I also came along the page of TU Chemnitz, but this seemed to be overkill. It just has to work quickly and without the overhead of custom-made devices.